# Should ASP.NET Themes and Skins Contain Spaces?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, themes

I am creating an ASP site with several high contrast themes. I have created other websites with themes, but this one is the first that will not change when a new theme is selected. I have a theory that theme and skin files should not contain spaces in the folder or file names, but I'm not sure. Any advice would be awesome. Here is my drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_SwitchTheme" runat="server" CssClass="BigText">
    <asp:ListItem Disabled="true" style="color: Silver;">High Contrast Themes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="color: Black; background-color: White; font-weight: bolder;">Black and White</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="color: White; background-color: Black; font-weight:    bolder;">Black and White Reverse</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="color: Yellow; background-color: Black; font-weight: bolder;"
Value="Black and Yellow">Yellow and Black</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="color: Black; background-color: Yellow; font-weight: bolder;"
Value="Black and Yellow">Yellow and Black Reverse</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="color: Yellow; background-color: Blue; font-weight: bolder;"
Value="Blue and Yellow">Blue and Yellow</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem style="color: Blue; background-color: Yellow; font-weight: bolder;"
Value="Blue and Yellow">Blue and Yellow Reverse</asp:ListItem>
...
...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And here is the code behind from the master page:

```
Partial Class Site
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim pageColor As String = ""
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Dim selectedTheme As String = Page.Theme
            Dim preferredTheme As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies.Get("PreferredTheme")
            If preferredTheme IsNot Nothing Then
                selectedTheme = preferredTheme.Value
            End If
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTheme) AndAlso DDL_SwitchTheme.Items.FindByValue(selectedTheme) IsNot Nothing Then
                DDL_SwitchTheme.Items.FindByValue(selectedTheme).Selected = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DDL_SwitchTheme_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DDL_SwitchTheme.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim preferredTheme As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("PreferredTheme")
        preferredTheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
        preferredTheme.Value = DDL_SwitchTheme.SelectedValue
        Response.Cookies.Add(preferredTheme)
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't matter. When I first asked this question, I had forgotten to add an important attribute to my dropdown list and checkbox - `AutoPostBack="True"`. I haven't had a second of trouble with theme names since I decided to try programming reversible themes again.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you never set the new selected theme to the page in your code.
Try something like that :

```
Protected Sub DDL_SwitchTheme_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DDL_SwitchTheme.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim preferredTheme As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("PreferredTheme")
        preferredTheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
        preferredTheme.Value = DDL_SwitchTheme.SelectedValue
        ' Set the new theme
        Page.Theme=DDL_SwitchTheme.SelectedValue

        Response.Cookies.Add(preferredTheme)
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString())
    End Sub
```

Comment: That's an awesome idea, but it is already being implemented in the BasePage class. I took this theme changing code straight from Wrox's Beginning ASP.NET 4 in C# & VB and it's never failed me until now.  I tried to put the method in this comment, but it didn't work, so it's in the main question.

Sorry I didn't answer sooner; I have another website project I'm working on that's going much better. :)